# Symfony 5 preserve session attribute after user logout

Tags: symfony, session, symfony4, symfony-security, symfony5

In https://symfony.com/doc/current/session.html it is said that "Stored attributes remain in the session for the remainder of that user's session."

Is there a way to keep session attributes when the user gets loged out?
If this is not ment to happen - how would I keep information over user login/logout/switches?

Comment: user data that should be persisted across sessions should be stored with the user in db, not in the session.

Comment: @user Have you verified that data stored on `Session` is actually cleared out on logout?

Comment: @Jakumi I don't want to persist user data across sessions. I want to use any data after user logout (no login happened then).

Comment: @yivi Yes I have done that. It is cleared out.